# how to resolve anaconda packages installation problem like 'KeyError:pkgs_dirs'?

Tags: anaconda, package, conda

when i install a package in old venv,as below:

```
(conda_venv)my-ubuntu:~/file$: conda install random
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json):failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File"/home/my/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py",line 1214, in print_unexpected_error_report message builder.append(get main info str(error report['conda info']))
File"/home/my/anaconda3/ib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 237, in get_main_info_str 
info dict[' '+ key] = ('\n’ + 26 *'').join(info dict[key]) 
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'
```

and

```
  enviroment variables:
conda info could not be constucted.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
```

and when i create a new venv,it shows the same error as above.
I found someone had the same prolem like me and they used "conda config --show-sources" to resolve,and i tried,but i got nothing but a blank line.

And i also tried "conda info",it showed

```
File"/home/my/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call return func(*args,**kwargs)
File "/home/my/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 87, in _main exit code = do call(args,p)
...
...
File "/home/my/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/ vendor/distro.py". line 599. in init
 self. lsb release info = self. get lsb release info() \
subprocess.CalledProcessError:Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 126
```

i don't know how to handle with this problem.I will appreciated it if any one can help.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Issues with `KeyError` can result from malformed configuration files. Please check your `.condarc` files are not corrupted (should be valid YAML). These can be located in three locations:

- user home (`~/.condarc`)
- Conda environment prefix (e.g., `/home/my/anaconda3/.condarc`, for OP)
- working directory

It also should be noted that it appears to be looking for a key `pkgs dirs` rather than the standard `pkgs_dirs`. Perhaps someone ran a `conda config --set 'pkgs dirs' '/path/to/blah'` by mistake?

Comment: well,'pkgs dirs' is a misspelling and i modified.And i used 'find -name ".condarc" ' ,but can't find where it is. and i also checked the directory you said and other locations, but still can't find it. But it makes me puzzled that i can run .py file in conda venv.it seems that i just can't create a new venv or install a package in my old venv. I swear that nobody changes my setup.Besides, the old venv was created 3 months ago .

Comment: You can try `conda config --show-sources`, but not sure if that triggers code that fails for you.

Comment: hello. i found the ".condarc " file and i set up some configurations.Now i try *conda config --show-sources*, it show envs_dirs ,pkgs_dirs and so on,i config the location of pakgs_dirs is /anaconda3/pkgs,i don't know whether it is wrong(maybe it should be /home/my/anaconda3/pkgs?) . but when i code *conda info *, it makes error as usual. And the ".condarc" file's type is plain text document instead of yaml(i don't whether they are same)

Comment: okay, then sounds like something else is the issue. this answer addresses a possible cause of KeyErrors, which may not even be the root issue

Comment: well,i will search for other solutions,thank you all the same